# Almacenar nombre y ruta de imagen para actualizar php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un código que me busca por medio del identificador PLACA unos datos, dentro de esos datos hay una imagen, la muestro por medio del temporal. hasta ahí todo bien, el problema viene cuando quiero actualizar los datos, hay veces que quiero actualizar la imagen y otras no, pero si actualizo cualquier dato se borra la imagen, y no se como almacenarla. intente ingenuamente colocando así `<input type="file" name="imagen1" id="imagen1" value="<?php echo $fila[$ruta1]; ?>">`, pero obviamente no funciono. PDT: Se que el código es básico y poco, pero no me quise extender mucho, también se que no debería de usar la librería mysql, pero es lo que hay por ahora.

**PHP**

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen6"]["tmp_name"])) {
  $ruta6= "FOTOS/".'_'.substr(sha1(rand(1,999)),0,-30).$_FILES["imagen6"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen6"]["tmp_name"], $ruta6);
} 

$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE huawei_parque_automotor SET PLACA=%s, imagen1=%s WHERE id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['PLACA'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($ruta1, "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));
```

**HTML**

```
<?php 
$rst_informe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM huawei_parque_automotor WHERE PLACA = '$PLACA'", $conexion);
$num_registros = mysql_num_rows($rst_informe);
?>

<?php 
  while ($fila=mysql_fetch_array($rst_informe))
  {    
?>

<td><input value="<?php echo $fila['PLACA']; ?>" type="text" name="PLACA" id="PLACA" /></td>
<td><img src="<?php echo $fila['imagen1']; ?>" alt="" width="125" height="125"/></td>

<?php
  }
?>

<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" />   

<input type="submit" name="Actualizar" id="Actualizar" value="Actualizar"/>
```

Comment: Si dices que no quieres que la imagen sea actualizada, entonces quítala de la consulta de actualización, la cual quedaría entonces así: **`UPDATE huawei_parque_automotor SET PLACA=%s WHERE id=%s`**

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunta, y respecto a lo que dices hay unas veces que si quiero actualizar la pregunta y otras que no.

Comment: Yo lo que haría sería sacar el del update el campo Foto, y solo cuando cargues una nueva foto, que supongo que eso lo tendrás controlado, actualizar el campo PLACA

Comment: Y de que forma se haría por que las imágenes las tengo dentro de un form

Comment: Déjame ver si entendí, tienes unos datos y los muestras en un form para actualizar, actualizas los datos pero no la imagen y al guardar se te borra la imagen que tenías anteriormente guardada?

Comment: Si, eso es lo que me pasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si sea la solución más óptima pero lo que yo haría es preguntar si viene la imagen, en caso de que si pues la guardo si no mantenemos la que estaba anteriormente:

```
if ($_FILES["imagen6"]["name"] != '') {
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen6"]["tmp_name"])) {
        $ruta6= "FOTOS/".'_'.substr(sha1(rand(1,999)),0,-30).$_FILES["imagen6"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen6"]["tmp_name"], $ruta6);
    } 

    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE huawei_parque_automotor SET PLACA=%s, imagen1=%s WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['PLACA'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($ruta1, "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));

}else{
    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE huawei_parque_automotor SET PLACA=%s WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['PLACA'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));
}
```

Comment: tengo otra pregunta, se que la debo postear pero es del mismo tema, y es: si tengo 2 imagenes o mas, es decir, `if ($_FILES["imagen6"]["name"] != '')` y `if ($_FILES["imagen7"]["name"] != '')` como le declararía, me pudes ayudar?

Comment: @AnderssonViveros y cada imagen tiene un campo diferente en la tabla?

Comment: si como imagen1, imagen2, imagen3... imagen8...

Comment: @AnderssonViveros lo que se me ocurre es hacer un if por cada una pero no veo eso nada viable, mejor realiza la pregunta y alguien puede mejorar mi idea

Answer (score 0):

No se te puede olvidar los input deben de ir dentro de las etiquetas form y dicha etiqueta debe tener el atributo enctype='multipart/form-data'